# find and list specific search with absolute path

Tags: grep, find, ls

I have been searching to perform a simple task i.e. traverse a folder path and find all file that have extension of .summary within a specific subfolder name and return as a ls command details but with an absolute path to the file.

here is the disk structure:-

```
-root--disk--folder1--subfolder--a.summary  
-root--disk--folder2--subfolder--b.summary  
-root--disk--folderX--subfolder--X.summary
```

here is what I have:-

```
ls -lR | grep summary  
-rw-r-----  1 username group 14150 Sep  8 22:41 a.summary  
-rw-r-----  1 username group 10150 Sep  9 22:41 b.summary
```

I am looking to get this result

```
-rw-r-----  1 username group 14150 Sep  8 22:41 /root/disk/folder1/subfolder/a.summary  
-rw-r-----  1 username group 10150 Sep  9 22:41 /root/disk/folder2/subfolder/b.summary
```

Is there a faster way complete the task if there are many paths that have Permission Denied issue?

Answer (score 1):

```
find /root/disk -path '*/subfolder/*.summary' -exec ls -ld {} +
```

(beware that with some `find` implementations, that assumes file paths are valid text in the current locale)

Note that it will find `.summary` files in directories called `subfolder` but also in subdirectories of those, the `*`s can span `/` characters in the `-path` above. To exclude files in subdirectories, you could add a `! -path '*/subfolder/*/*'` though it would also exclude `/root/disk/subfolder/foo/subfolder/a.summary` for instance.  Some `find` implementations have a `-regex` to match on paths with regular expressions where you could use `-regex '.*/subfolder/[^/]*\.summary'`.

With several `find` implementations, you can use just `-ls` in place of `-exec ls -ld {} +` with a slightly different output format (and no sorting of file paths¹).

To hide the errors about inaccessible directories, you can redirect the errors to `/dev/null` with `2> /dev/null`.

Or just use `zsh`:

```
ls -ld /root/disk/**/subfolder/*.summary(DoN)
```

No locale problem, sorted list², but note that if `disk` or `subfolder` directories are symlinks to directories, they will be traversed, and the command may fail if the list of files is too big (see `zargs` to work around that).

To avoid the traversing the `subfolder` symlinks, you could change it to:

```
ls -ld /root/dir/**/*.summary(DoNe['[[ $REPLY:h:t = subfolder ]]'])
```

Using the `e`val glob qualifier to check that the `t`ail of the `h`ead of the path is `subfolder` (`**/` never follows symlinks in zsh).

---

<sup>¹ with `-exec ls -ld {} +`, `ls` will sort the files it receives as arguments by name, though note that `ls` may be invoked several times if there's a very large number of files so files may end up displayed in independently sorted batches.</sup>

<sup>² here we're using the `oN` glob qualifier to `N`ot `o`rder the list in the glob as an optimisation on the ground that `ls` will do its own sorting anyway.</sup>

Comment: +1 I completely forgot path

Answer (score 0):

To fetch the files ending with `extension` and their parent should be a directory named `subfolder`:

```
find . -type d -name subfolder -exec sh -c 'ls -l "$0"/*.extension' {} \;
```

or you can use execdir option

```
find . -type f -name '*.extension' -execdir bash -c '[ "$(basename "$PWD")" == "subfolder" ] && echo "$PWD/$0"' {} \;
```

Comment: thank you all. the find command works as needed. appreciate the quick respond.